# Nested functions (using IF, SUMIF and AND functions)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a situation where I need to check two conditions and when both are **0** then it should show **0.00** in cell J17 other wise it should calculate using follwing Sumifs function i.e. **SUMIFS('input'!$Q$60:$Q$65,'input'!$A$60:$A$65,Growth_Factors!$A$17:$A$31)))** and show the total sum value

1st Condition: **If(SUMIFS('input'!$Q$60:$Q$65,'input'!$A$60:$A$65,Growth_Factors!$A$17:$A$31)=0**

2nd Condition:
**IF(AND(K17=0,M17=0,O17=0,Q17=0,T17=0,V17=0,X17=0,Z17=0,AC17=0,AE17=0,AG17=0,AI17=0,AL17=0,AN17=0,AP17=0,AR17=0,AU17=0,AW17=0,AY17=0,BA17=0)**

But in second condition when any of the columns having more than 0, then column J17 should show value as **0.001**

I have tried the below formula, but is working when both conditions are met which is **0**, if I add any value in the 2nd condition, then the below mentioned formula not working.

Can someone please help me on this?

**=IF(SUMIFS('input'!$Q$60:$Q$65,'input'!$A$60:$A$65,Growth_Factors!$A$17:$A$31)=0,IF(AND(K17=0,M17=0,O17=0,Q17=0,T17=0,V17=0,X17=0,Z17=0,AC17=0,AE17=0,AG17=0,AI17=0,AL17=0,AN17=0,AP17=0,AR17=0,AU17=0,AW17=0,AY17=0,BA17=0),0,SUMIFS('input'!$Q$60:$Q$65,'input'!$A$60:$A$65,Growth_Factors!$A$17:$A$31)))**

Comment: So, if Condition 1 and 2 are 0, the result is 0. If Condition 1 is 0 but not Condition 2, then the result should be 0.01. If Condition 1 is not 0, then the result should be the `SUMIFS` (no matter what Condition 2 is). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.  You're right Jerry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misplaced an expression in the nested `IF` conditions. Try this:

```
=IF(SUMIFS('input'!$Q$60:$Q$65,'input'!$A$60:$A$65,Growth_Factors!$A$17:$A$31)=0,
   IF(AND(K17=0,M17=0,O17=0,Q17=0,T17=0,V17=0,X17=0,Z17=0,AC17=0,AE17=0,AG17=0,AI17=0,AL17=0,AN17=0,AP17=0,AR17=0,AU17=0,AW17=0,AY17=0,BA17=0),
     0,
     0.001),
   SUMIFS('input'!$Q$60:$Q$65,'input'!$A$60:$A$65,Growth_Factors!$A$17:$A$31)
 )
```

I added indentation so that you see what the true and false evaluations are.

As you can see, in the inner `IF`, there is only `0` and `0.001`. The `SUMIFS` comes outside, in the outer `IF`.

Comment: Super Jerry.  This is what I wanted.  Thank you so much.